# DOM element not being found after cloning and appending unique ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm creating a random string value:

```
var randomString = function(stringLength) {
    var i = 0;
    stringLength = stringLength || 10;
    var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var randomString = '';
    for (i = 0; i < stringLength; i += 1) {
        var rNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomString += chars.substring(rNum, rNum + 1);
    }
    return randomString;
};
```

And associating it with a list element on one pane:

```
var addUniqueId = function($thumbnail) {
    var random = randomString(10);
    $thumbnail.attr('id', 'rand-' + random);
};
```

And then cloning it and moving that list element to the right:

```
    var cloneImage = function($thumbnail) {
        addUniqueId($thumbnail);
        var $lastImgAdded = $('.js-gallery-edit-pane li').last();
        var span = $('<span />');
        span.addClass('x').text('x');
        var $clone = $thumbnail.clone(true, true).appendTo($('.js-gallery-edit-pane')).prepend(span).hide().fadeIn(200).unbind('click');
        bindRemoveHandler($clone);
    };
```

Then I add an overlay to the list element on the left to "gray" it out. Everything works at this point.

From there, a user can remove the recently cloned items on the right hand side by clicking the "X" on the image. This works fine and removes that recently cloned image, however, the original overlay is not being found. It should be associated with the random string value, so I'm just looking for that in `$('.js-gallery-select-pane').find('#rand-' + string).find('.overlay').remove();` but for some reason it's not finding it...

Any idea why?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CSM8d/)

Comment: you are adding the id to original , then cloning... now have 2 with same ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put an `alert(string)` in your code, you will see that the string already includes `rand-` so in your selector just do:

```
$('.js-gallery-select-pane').find('#' + string).find('.overlay').remove();
```

Here is the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSM8d/1/)

Comment: +1 - Don't forget to remove the js-gallery-editing class or you won't be able to clone the image to the right if you clone it once, then remove it. `$('.js-gallery-select-pane').find('#' + string).removeClass('js-gallery-editing').find('.overlay').remove();`

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I was overlooking that. Thanks for pointing that out to me and the quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two collections of elements with ID pairs in them.

There's three problems though. The first two problems problem are here..

You were taking the complete id of the clone 'rand-etctcetc'
then adding rand- to it again 'rand-rand-etcetcetc' then using it as a selector. $('rand-rand-etcetcetc'). Instead I changed it to just add the neccessary # to the id. You also need to remove the js-gallery-editing class in order to let you add things back to the list on right hand side.

```
    var bindRemoveHandler = function($thumbnail) {
      $thumbnail.on('click', function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200, function() {
          var string = $(this).attr('id');
          $('.js-gallery-select-pane').find('#' + string).removeClass('js-gallery-editing').find('.overlay').remove();
          $(this).remove();
          updatePictureCount();
        });
      });
    };
```

You could stop here but, you also have a different problem. The ID attribute is intended to be unique. Try using a custom attribute and the Jquery attribute equals selector. The query you want would look something like this..

```
     $('.js-gallery-select-pane').find('[pairid="' + string +'"]');
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s3dCB/